# How to copy all datatables from one dataset to another with 2 differents db connection?

Tags: c#

Let's say I want to transfer data from MySQL to MS Access any sample code to do so ? Of course this has to take into account constraints in schema.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason for doing so (such as a process that needs to be done repeatedly), I would use the MS Access "Import" process rather than coding a solution.  It's much easier.

Better yet, use the Linked Tables feature in Access to link directly to the MySql tables if you want a live link that never has to be imported again.

Comment: Yes I have a good reason: I don't have MS Access App, only the file :)